# Data analysis of log files – How to find a pattern?

Tags: python, logging, windows-ce, data-analysis

My company has slightly more than 300 vehicle based windows CE 5.0 mobile devices that all share the same software and usage model of Direct Store Delivery during the day then doing a Tcom at the home base every night.  There is an unknown event(s) that results in the device freaking out and rebooting itself in the middle of the day.  Frequency of this issue is ~10 times per week across the fleet of computers that all reboot daily, 6 days a week.  The math is 300*6=1800 boots per week (at least) 10/1800= 0.5%.  I realize that number is very low, but it is more than my boss wants to have.

My challenge, is to find a way to scan through several thousand logfille.txt files and try to find some sort of pattern.  I KNOW there is a pattern here somewhere. I’ve got a couple ideas of where to start, but I wanted to throw this out to the community and see what suggestions you all might have.

A bit of background on this issue.  The application starts a new log file at each boot.  In an orderly (control) log file, you see the app startup, do its thing all day, and then start a shutdown process in a somewhat orderly fashion 8-10 hours later.  In a problem log file, you see the device startup and then the log ends without any shutdown sequence at all in a time less than 8 hours.  It then starts a new log file which shares the same date as the logfile1.old that it made in the rename process.  The application that we have was home grown by windows developers that are no longer with the company.  Even better, they don’t currently know who has the source at the moment.

I’m aware of the various CE tools that can be used to detect memory leaks (DevHealth, retail messages, etc..) and we are investigating that route as well, however I’m convinced that there is a pattern to be found, that I’m just not smart enough to find. There has to be a way to do this using Perl or Python that I’m just not seeing. Here are two ideas I have.

Idea 1 –  Look for trends in word usage.
Create an array of every unique word used in the entire log file and output a count of each word.  Once I had a count of the words that were being used, I could run some stats on them and look for the non-normal events.  Perhaps the word “purple” is being used 500 times in a 1000 line log file ( there might be some math there?) on a control and only 4 times on a 500 line problem log?  Perhaps there is a unique word that is only seen in the problem files.  Maybe I could get a reverse “word cloud”?

Idea 2 – categorize lines into entry-type and then look for trends in the sequence of type of entry type?
The logfiles already have a predictable schema that looks like this =  Level|date|time|system|source|message
I’m 99% sure there is a visible pattern here that I just can’t find.  All of the logs got turned up to “super duper verbose” so there is a boatload of fluff (25 logs p/sec , 40k lines per file) that makes this even more challenging.  If there isn’t a unique word,  then this has almost got to be true.  How do I do this?

Item 3 – Hire a windows CE platform developer
Yes, we are going down that path as well, but I KNOW there is a pattern I’m missing.  They will use the tools that I don’t have) or make the tools that we need to figure out what’s up.  I suspect that there might be a memory leak, radio event or other event that platform tools I’m sure will show.

Item 4 – Something I’m not even thinking of that you have used.
There have got to be tools out there that do this that aren’t as prestigious as a well-executed python script, and I’m willing to go down that path, I just don’t know what those tools are.

Oh yeah, I can’t post log files to the web, so don’t ask.  The users are promising to report trends when they see them, but I’m not exactly hopeful on that front.  All I need to find is either a pattern in the logs, or steps to duplicate

So there you have it.  What tools or techniques can I use to even start on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no input data at all to this problem so this answer will be basically pure theory, a little collection of ideas you could consider.

1. To analize patterns out of a bunch of many logs you could definitely creating some graphs displaying relevant data which could help to narrow the problem, python is really very good for these kind of tasks.
2. You could also transform/insert the logs into databases, that way you'd be able to query the relevant suspicious events much faster and even compare massively all your logs.
3. A simpler approach could be just focusing on a simple log showing the crash, instead wasting a lot of efforts or resources trying to find some kind of generic pattern, start by reading through one simple log in order to catch suspicious "events" which could produce the crash.
4. My favourite approach for these type of tricky problems is different from the previous ones, instead of focusing on analizing or even parsing the logs I'd just try to reproduce the bug/s in a deterministic way locally (you don't even need to have the source code). Sometimes it's really difficult to replicate the production environment in your the dev environment but definitely is time well invested. All the effort you put into this process will help you to solve not only these bugs but improving your software much faster. Remember, the more times you're able to iterate the better.
5. Another approach could just be coding a little script which would allow you to replay logs which crashed, not sure if that'll be easy in your environment though. Usually this strategy works quite well with production software using web-services where there will be a lot of tuples with data-requests and data-retrieves.

In any case, without seeing the type of data from your logs I can't be more specific nor giving much more concrete details.

Answer (score 0):

was wondering if you'd looked at the ELK stack?  It's an acronym for elasticsearch, kibana and log stash and fits your use case closely; it's often used for analysis of large numbers of log files.

Elasticsearch and kibana gives you a UI that lets you interactively explore and chart data for trends.  Very powerful and quite straight forward to set up on a Linux platform and there's a Windows version too. (Took me a day or two of setup but you get a lot of functional power from it). Software is free to download and use.  You could use this in a style similar to idea 1 / 2

https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack

http://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/

On the question of Python / idea 4 (which elk could be considered part of) I haven't done this for log files but I have used Regex to search and extract text patterns from documents using Python.  That may also help you find patterns if you had some leads on the sorts of patterns you are looking for.

Just a couple of thoughts; hope they help.